# Unable to open Hidden folder on USB Drive

Tags: windows-10, usb

On Windows 10 have a 4GB USB Drive (D:) on FAT32

According to properties menu, it has used space of 3.05 GB

There is only one hidden folder on it (Fig 1 below); when you right click>properties on that, it shows as 0 bytes. The folder name also appears unusual, I dont know what the third character represents. (Note I have purposely blacked out the remainder of the folder name)

Double clicking on the folder brings up a message that it is not accessible (Fig 2)

User asked me to try and recover the contents so:

1. Tried to rename folder - cannot
2. ran Recuva - deep scan - which only picked up a PDF file which I had copied to the drive and deleted as a test to see if the disk was still useable

Any suggestions how to access the contents of this disk?

[image: Fig 1]

[image: Fig 2]

Comment: Try running a disk check: Right-click the disk and select 'Properties', then go to 'Tools', then click 'Check'. Click on 'Scan for and attempt recovery of bad sector', then let it do its thing.

Comment: @Virtuality, that worked.

Comment: Well, glad to hear that! I will post it as a solution.

Comment: You can mark it as the accepted solution if you feel it helped

Comment: Click on the green tick to mark as the solution so others know this question has been answered, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running a disk check:

- Right-click the disk and select 'Properties'
- Go to the 'Tools' tab, then click 'Check'.
- Click on 'Scan for and attempt recovery of bad sector', then let it do its thing.

Comment: A much quicker way of doing the same would be `WinKey`+`R` > `chkdsk /f D:` || `chkdsk /f /b D:` || `chkdsk /offlinescanandfix D:` _(see `chkdsk /?` or [man page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk))_. _(General FYI: please leave salutations out of questions/answers)_